# Spring Cloud Gateway doesn't work with @Bean DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway

I follow Spring Tips: Spring Cloud Gateway. But my gateway app doesn't create routes from the service register(Eureka). DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator constructor with 2 params. The gateway app it's not routing from Eureka server. I've been trying changing the versions in the pom.xml but I'm using the RELEASE.

The **Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class GatewayApplication {

    @Bean
    DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator discoveryRoutes(DiscoveryClient dc, DiscoveryLocatorProperties dlp) {
        return new DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator(dc, dlp);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The constructor of the DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator is using now 2 params instead just 1 like in the Spring Tips: Spring Clou Gateway.

The **application.property**:

```
spring.application.name=gateway
server.port=8081
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
```

My **pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.hcl.cnp</groupId>
<artifactId>gateway</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>gateway</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

Comment: I've edited your `application.poperty` to `application.property` in your question: I hope that wasn't your actual issue. Please follow up on how you fixed your issue.

Answer (score 3):

To let it works. You don't need to add the bean below, remove it

```
@Bean
DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator discoveryRoutes(DiscoveryClient dc, DiscoveryLocatorProperties dlp) {
    return new DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator(dc, dlp);
}
```

In your application.properties, add these two lines to enable discovery client

```
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lower-case-service-id=true
```

And it should work!

Answer (score 1):

The constructor **DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator**(DiscoveryClient, DiscoveryLocatorProperties) is deprecated

I suggest you to use :

**ReactiveDiscoveryClient** instead of **DiscroveryClient**

```
@Bean
DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator discoveryRoutes(ReactiveDiscoveryClient rdc,
        DiscoveryLocatorProperties dlp) {
    return new DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator(rdc, dlp);
}
```

Other thing, you should rename your **application.proporty** to **application.properities**